# Round off multiple columns to decimal values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, rounding

How to round off multiple columns (0,1,2,3,4) to 2 decimal places using round() function in the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5)*100000).astype(int)
df


      0       1       2       3       4
0   49906   39916   72010   53698   47876
```

Expected output

```
     0            1           2           3           4
0   49906.00    39916.00    72010.00    53698.00    47876.00
```

Update:

Can we use round() to convert int datatype?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5)*100).astype(int)
print(df.dtypes)

df.round(2)

0    int32

    0   1   2   3   4
0   59  84  38  21  97
```

Comment: Sorry, why is first value `0.26` ? Also main question is why not working `round(2)`, so is possible see wrong output from `df.round(2)` and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael - The output which i have given is just an example.I am trying to use and learn round() in multiple datasets .So is there any nice method to convert to 2 decimal places?

Comment: `df.round(2)` isn't working as you expected? What exactly is your question?

Comment: hmmm, `round(2)` should working here perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! If the datatype is int64 ,then do we have to convert them to float and use round() ?

Comment: No, you can also round integers directly (i.e. without converting them to float), which of course only makes sense for negative arguments, e.g. `round(-1)` rounds to multiples of 10.

Comment: @stef - i try to round off int value but couldnot do that as you can see in update!

Comment: in the update you try to round and integer to 2 decimal places which is pointless as an integer has no decimals. It's not clear what is your issue or what do you want to achieve. Maybe you could provide given data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In this question, you are asking about three different `round()` functions, one from base Python, one from [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) and one from [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html).

Whichever you choose to work with, they will only change results if you apply them onto `float` variables/numbers. Decimal points are applicable to `float` variables and not `int` variables. In this example you are using it on an `int` variable that is why you see no change.

If you are intending to learn how they work, here is my suggested format:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5)*100000).astype(float)
df

    0               1               2               3               4
0   96570.941944    22732.301549    81830.757577    58857.086372    4907.195818
1   4241.326114     85368.514655    33762.159792    23861.687575    19567.704272
2   33538.362394    37209.378107    32019.115854    31081.772016    57019.042559
3   78375.785808    73739.289518    47778.567064    14235.519877    63688.667891
4   38567.188748    62989.825006    33054.391804    11272.785510    84433.674789

# The pandas way:
df.round(2)
    0           1           2           3           4
0   96570.94    22732.30    81830.76    58857.09    4907.20
1   4241.33     85368.51    33762.16    23861.69    19567.70
2   33538.36    37209.38    32019.12    31081.77    57019.04
3   78375.79    73739.29    47778.57    14235.52    63688.67
4   38567.19    62989.83    33054.39    11272.79    84433.67
```

and if you do the python way, `round(df,2)`, or the `numpy` way, `np.round(df,2)`, you should get the same result.

Comment: How will you do it if you only want the unique values but still rounded off?